# SAP By Design CPI/HCI GUI - Content modifier block to set Content-Type

Tags: sap-cpi, sap-business-bydesign

I've got a simple scenario - getting some customer data out of SAP by design, and sending this data as a POST request to a third party endpoint.

The third party endpoint will only accept POST requests with a header of Content-Type of application/json

So I set up a Content Modifier block, as shown below:

[image: Content modifier block]

[image: Content modifier block details]

And then on the actual HTTP request I've put in the headers (the apikey header seems to work fine)

[image: HTTP request block details]

I've tried various things such as trying to set the content header of the message in groovy script

[image: Groovy script method to change Content-Type message header]

But all attempts have failed.

Just for completeness - the 3rd party API returns a 415 status code (Unsupported Media Type), and yes, if I use Postman with the correct Content-Type I get a 200 response.

Any pointers would be welcome